# How can I get my website to post data to my mysql database?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm learning php, and I have done the whole posting into my database from my site, except now I am doing it with prepared statements, I found that it wasn't working. So I deleted the table and I created a whole new one, I've established a connection between my database and my site. The problem I'm having is that no data from my form will post as data to my mysql database.

**HERES MY INDEX FILE**

```
    <?php 
include_once 'include/dbh.php';

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<form action="include/signup.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="last"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="uid"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>




</body>                                                                   

</html>
```

**Thats my form, next is the connection to the database.**

```
<?php 

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "phplessons";

$conn = mysqli_connect ($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

**Lastly my signup page**

```
<?php 

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, uid, pwd)
        VALUES (first, last, email, uid, pwd);";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: ../index.php?signup=successsss");
```

Comment: You define but don't use your post variables

Comment: So what should i use GET instead

Comment: No, change your query to what I posted as an answer

Comment: I cannot find what you have posted as an answer, please help me out.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, uid, pwd)
    VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$pwd');";

Comment: I have pasted that and replaced it with my code yet it seems to still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use your variable. Use single quotations around your variable. 
Example '$first', '$last' .....

Comment: That i have fixed yet their is still no data in my database. Is their a place where we can chat and help me fix my problem.